# PHP вывод даты с буквенным месяцем

Tags: php, дата, вывод

Чем можно заменить следующий код

```js
switch (substr($bill['from'], 5, 2)) {
  case '01':
    {
      $str_from = substr($bill['from'], 3, 2).
      ' января '.substr($bill['from'], 0, 4);
    }
    break;
  case '02':
    {
      $str_from = substr($bill['from'], 3, 2).
      ' февраля '.substr($bill['from'], 0, 4);
    }
    break;
    .......
  case '12':
    {
      $str_from = substr($bill['from'], 3, 2).
      ' декабря '.substr($bill['from'], 0, 4);
    }
    break;
}
```

```js
$bill['from']='2015-08-15 15:15:15';
//свитч
echo $str;
//вывод: "15 августа 2015"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$bill['from']='2015-08-15 15:15:15';
$date = strtotime($bill['from']);
$month_names = array(1 => 'января', 2 => 'февраля', 3 => 'марта',   4 => 'апреля',
    5 => 'мая', 6 => 'июня', 7 => 'июля', 8 => 'августа',
    9 => 'сентября', 10 => 'октября', 11 => 'ноября', 12 => 'декабря');
$month_name = $month_names[date('n', $date)];
$str_from = date("d ", $date).$month_name.date(" Y", $date);
```

> 15 августа 2015

Comment: гениально...искал для вывода числа прописью-похожий механизм,а додуматься заюзать для такого не додумался)))спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через функцию например:

```
  function months($eng_date){
    $eng_date=date('j.m.Y',strtotime($eng_date));
    $date=explode(".", $eng_date);
    switch ($date[1]){
    case 1:  $m='января';   break;
    case 2:  $m='февраля';  break;
    case 3:  $m='марта';    break;
    case 4:  $m='апреля';   break;
    case 5:  $m='мая';      break;
    case 6:  $m='июня';     break;
    case 7:  $m='июля';     break;
    case 8:  $m='августа';  break;
    case 9:  $m='сентября'; break;
    case 10: $m='октября';  break;
    case 11: $m='ноября';   break;
    case 12: $m='декабря';  break;
    }
    return $date[0].' '.$m.' '.$date[2];
    }
```

Вывод на страницу через echo();

```
echo months("2015-08-15 15:15:15");
```